# Strange behavior, about Interface to be a member of a class in Java

Tags: java

```
interface SomeInterface {
    String test = "hello";
}

public class SomeCls {
    SomeInterface sif;
    public static void main(){
        SomeCls cls = new SomeCls();
        cls.sif = null;
        System.out.println(cls.sif.test); // still work.
    }
}
```

I'm coming from c++, question is:

1) because interface is a "abstract" type, how can it be used as a member, I mean, how to init it?

2) I know, the member "sif" may be just a reference(not like the c++ reference, more like a pointer in c), but since I set it reference to null. how can it still output the interface's field?

Comment: What do you mean it works? Have you compiled it? Have you ran it without NullPointerException?

Comment: yes, javac, version 8

Comment: The interface `String test` is a constant, so there is constant propagation when you access `test`

Comment: Can't test this, but I think what's really happening is this  `System.out.println(SomeInterface.test);`, so it doesn't matter if the interface is null

Comment: @cricket_007 yes, maybe it just a "static member" for SomeInterface

Comment: Right, that's what Elliott means by constant propagation. It's a string constant in the interface, so you can access it without an instance of the interface. The compiler recognizes when you use the instance variable, but rewrites it to use the constant

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Variable declared inside an interface would be static by default. So it doesnt make sense to call that variable using reference .

You can call like `SomeInterface.test`

Comment: So, in java, we can access static member in two ways: type.field or instance.field?

Comment: Thats correct. But again, using  `instance.field` doesnt make sense at all since there will be only one copy of `field`

Answer (score 1):

About your first question.

You can't create instance of interface. But you can create implementation of interface:

```
public class SomeClass implements SomeInterface{
   ...
}
```

And as you correctly noted, variable of interface type *"may be just a reference"*

```
SomeInterface sif = new SomeClass();
```

You can consider interface like a contract, description of behavior, that class (witch implements this interface) promise to provide.

Another point, there is no multiple inheritance in Java, but class can implement multiple interfaces.